# System.Linq.Queryable.Except is not supported in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Please note this error message :

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not parse expression
> 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable
> This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except' is
> currently not supported.'

Is supported in newer versions of ef core?

my code :

```
        var tuple = SearchBrand(searchTerm);
        var result = GetExceptionsBrand(tuple.Item1, categoryId);
        return Json(new
        {
            iTotalDisplayRecords = tuple.Item2,
            iDisplayedBrand = result
                .Skip(page * 10)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList(),
        });
        
public async Task<Tuple<IQueryable<BrandDto>, int, int>>SearchBrand(string searchTerm)
        {
        
        var result = _context.Brands
            .Where(c => c.IsDeleted == displayIsDeleted)
            .WhereDynamic(searchTerm)
        return new Tuple<IQueryable<BrandDto>, int, int>(result, 
        filteredResultsCount, totalResultsCount);
         }

       
public IQueryable<BrandDto> GetExceptionsBrand(IEnumerable<BrandDto> filteredBrand, int categoryId)
    {
        var query = _context.CategoriesBrands.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);
        var selectedList = new List<BrandDto>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            var cb = new BrandDto()
            {
                BrandDto_BrandId = item.BrandId
                
            };
            selectedList.Add(cb);
        }
        IQueryable<BrandDto> ExcpetList = filteredBrand.AsQueryable().Except(selectedList, new ComparerBrand());
        return ExcpetList;
    }
```

Comment: "*Is supported in newer versions of ef core?"* (1) What EF Core version are *you* using? (2) What is the failing query (looks like there is unsupported `Except` method overload (with equality comparer?), but we need to see it)?

Comment: @IvanStoev : im using ef core 2.1

Comment: Ok, now the query. And please include both in the question, not in comments.

Comment: If you are using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.except?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_Except__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__), it isn't and won't be supported. If you are using the "regular" `Except`, it depends - we need to see the query.

Comment: @IvanStoev : 
Query added Please take a look

Comment: Well, see my previous comment - you are using the exact `Except` overload I linked to, it is NOT supported and will NOT be supported by EF Core. You have to find another way to achieve the goal. Or execute the query client side by removing `AsQueryable()`, e.g. `return filteredBrand.Except(selectedList, new ComparerBrand()).AsQueryable();` Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev : return filteredBrand.Except(selectedList, new ComparerBrand()).AsQueryable() it's work thank you so very much